# azure devops jobs downloads where it cannot read

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am working on a simple yaml pipeline. Two jobs. First compiles, second is supposed to deploy. The compile works fine, the deploy downloads the zip of compilation and then fails to access the file for deployment.

```
- deployment: deploy
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  dependsOn: Cake_CI
  condition: variables.isMain
  displayName: DeployMyJob
  environment: Dev
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: dir /s /b $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\..
          displayName: Directory Listing
        - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
          inputs:
            WebAppName: 'mywebapp'
            azureSubscription: 'mysubscription'
            package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/EventExport/EventExport.zip'
            deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'
            appType: 'webApp'
```

Apparently the download occurs before the dir task in the above. Downmload Artifact task is implicit and shows the following

```
Download from the specified build: #381301
Download artifact to: D:\a\1/
```

The dir command shows following listing including EventExport.zip, this validates the download location.

```
D:\a\1\a
D:\a\1\b
D:\a\1\EventExport
D:\a\1\s
D:\a\1\TestResults
D:\a\1\EventExport\EventExport.zip
```

Deployment fails because it is looking for the file in the wrong place.

```
##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s\EventExport\EventExport.zip
```

Now where is the disconnect between download and use of the package within the same job.
Thanks to everyone who looks into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` is inside the `s` folder: `D:\a\1\s`. and the `.zip` exist in `D:\a\1`.

So you can tell him to go one folder up:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/../EventExport/EventExport.zip
```

Comment: the second agent now looks in "a" directory instead of "s" - Error "No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\a\EventExport\EventExport.zip", Tried by only giving EventExport/EventExport.zip and it again wants to access it under "s".

Comment: I got it working as $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/../EventExport/EventExport.zip
There must be a better way though.

Comment: @Tauqir try this variable `Agent.BuildDirectory` (instead of `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`)

Comment: tried already, didnt work.

Comment: I asked someone and it appears that deployment jobs can download at the root folder of pipeline "work/1" in this case. and customizing package path is normal. So ".." is not so bad. I will go ahead and accept your answer, if you will be so kind as to update it a little. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk It worked for me. I was using only CopyFiles as a part of my build pipeline. Then to make it available I was trying Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory. It did not work. But when I changed to Agent.BuildDirectory it workd. Thanks!!